# Complete build package of "pdftotext" for deploying on AWS-Lambda with Python3.7

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, pdftotext

I am trying to deploy a small python 3.7 code which uses "pdftotext" on AWS-Lambda.  I was able to run the code successfully on my local machine (Mac).  Using virtual-environment as specified by AWS documentation, I created a deployment package of the code with pdftotext.  However still I am getting module not found error in Lambda.  If you have been able to create a complete build package for pdftotext with all its dependencies, can you share please.  Thanks in advance.

Using virtual-environment as specified by AWS documentation, I created a deployment package of the code with pdftotext.

```
import pdftotext
```

Getting module not found error for pdftotext when testing in AWS-Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party on the answer to this question, but I asked a similar question here: [Get pdftotext Python module running on Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64442744/get-pdftotext-python-module-running-on-lambda)

My problem was I was compiling the binary on Amazon Linux 1 when the Python 3.8 lambda runtime uses Amazon Linux 2 shared libraries.

Install the library on an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance or docker container, and the library will be usable in your lambda.

Posting this in case it helps someone that comes across this question.