# Get pdftotext Python module running on Lambda

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, pdftotext, poppler

I need to get the `pdftotext` python library for 3.8.6 running in an AWS Lambda Function.

I have the library installed and running on an Amazon Linux AMI, however when I copy the library files into a lambda I get:

```
[ERROR] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdftotext' Traceback (most recent call last)
```

The lambda function has the Python path set to the `site-packages` directory, which I have confirmed is the same on the Amazon Linux instance. Other libraries in the same directory can be imported fine.

The python package is an actual binary (pdftotext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so), and I'm assuming the binary generated on the Amazon Linux AMI isn't compatible with lambda? So perhaps this is the reason it can't be imported.

I've also attempted to install the library in the Amazon Linux docker container (amazonlinux:2018.03), but when importing the module I get the following error:

```
ImportError: /root/package/lib/pdftotext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7poppler8document18load_from_raw_dataEPKciRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_
```

Has anybody got this working? Or any ideas on things I can try / steps I can table to troubleshoot?

Comment: Lambda Python 3.8 uses Amazon Linux 2, not Amazon Linux 1. Have you tried using shared libraries from AL2?

Comment: Thanks so much for this, this was the issue - please post an answer and I'll accept, otherwise I will answer myself.

Comment: Thank you. Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using Amazon Linux 1 (AL1), instead of AL2. This is because **Lambda environment for Python 3.8 is based on AL2**, not AL1.

The **solution** was to use the shared objects needed for `pdftotext` from AL2, rather then from AL1.

Comment: Hey there, i ran into the same problem but i dont know how to change my lambda enviroment from al1 to al2, could you give me a hand?